# JSF- How to get the previous selected row index from datatable?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, datatable

I want to retain the value of previously selected row index to compare it with the currently selected rown index.How can I able to get the previous index in backing bean from a datatable in jsf ?
Here is the sample code for getting the current index from datatable.

```
public void setindexvalue(DateSelectEvent event) {


        int index = Integer.parseInt(((String) event.getComponent()
                .getAttributes().get("index")).replace("_", ""));
        System.out.println("Index:\t" + index);
}
```

I am calling the above method in JSF XHTML using the below code :

```
    <p:ajax event="dateSelect"    listener="#{Bean.setindexvalue}" />
 <f:attribute name="index" value="_#{rowIndex}" />
```

The above code is inside a datatable for a specific cell and I want to call the "setindexvalue" each time when a row gets selected, but when I click the next row **somehow,I want to retain the value of previously selected row  index in backing bean.So that  I can compare the current index with the previous index** 
How can I able to do it ?

Comment: Have a temparary variable in your bean to store previously selected value. There is no facility in the datatable component to provide that.

Comment: @SrikanthGanji Ganji - how can you do that? Can yu able to give some sample code here ? Coz you have to retain the previously selected row each time when you are clicking a new row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
private int previous_index;

public void setindexvalue(DateSelectEvent event) {

        int index = Integer.parseInt(((String) event.getComponent()
                .getAttributes().get("index")).replace("_", ""));
        System.out.println("Index:\t" + index);

// Here you have your previous index stored in the variable and can do the comparison

        previous_index = index;
}
```